# Google cardboard missing prefab

Tags: android, object, google-cardboard

All guides I have seen like:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfG63Ge3aQk
have a main prefab, but I have NEVER found any package remotely close to containing a camera. Also when I follow the guide and download the package:
https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/download#google-vr-sdk-for-unity
Even the demo scenes have no special camera and contain faults.

Also to do without I have used unity input.gyro.attitude, but it gives weird movements when the phone is still

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the CardboardMain prefab is no longer included in the sdk. I'm pretty sure that now you just need to enable the Cardboard sdk in player settings ("virtual reality supported" checkbox) and add a GvR Raycaster script to your main camera.